# Yarn install stuck on building packages

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, yarnpkg, supabase

after yarn install complete, it seems started another thread and it just sutck at there forever, doese somebody ever had this problem? Is this a problem of supabase?
[stuck after finishied building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8xjL.png)

---

the package.json is like this

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF44j.png)

---

current node version: 18.15.0, but i have tried on 16.14.0, it had this same problem.
yarn version: 1.22.19

i have tried change node version, clear yarn cache or even just using npm install and still had the same problem.